# Number of folders which don't have subfolders

Tags: bash, unix, find

I don't have a clue how to "simply" get the number of folders which don't have subfolders.
I found something with `-printf "%h\n"` in `find` but, I am not sure what this is for.

Comment: There's lots of help here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18886367

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14912513.  Interesting that folks want to find folders with *two* subfolders.  It should be easy enough to modify that code for zero subfolders.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The question linked in the supposedly answered question is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: That's all right.  The OP has already indicated that he can make it work, and whether the number of folders is zero, two or 42 doesn't make that much difference.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I'll reopen it for you.

Comment: If your file system supports hardlinks, the easiest way is to use the `-links` option to `find` as @BenJackson suggested in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14917866/1331399) to the linked question. For example: `find -type d -links 2`.

Comment: @Thor, please post your comment as an answer and I will upvote it!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I think referring to the answer is enough in this case.

Answer (score 2):

- To determine the folders in current directory that don't possess subfolders (not considering hidden ones):

  ```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; a=( "$1"/*/ ); ((${#a[@]}==0)); exit $?' _ {} \; -print
  ```
- Taking hidden ones into account (but not `.` and `..` of course):

  ```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob dotglob; a=( "$1"/*/ ); ((${#a[@]}==0)); exit $?' _ {} \; -print
  ```

If you want to recurse into folders (i.e., also determine subfolders with this property), just remove the `-maxdepth 1` part of the command.

There are other ways of course: 100% pure bash, or, funnier, using a `find` inside `find` as so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -execdir sh -c 'find "$1" -mindepth 1 -type d -print -quit | read a' _ {} \; -print
```

Note that these methods are 100% regarding filenames containing funny symbols (spaces, newlines, leading/trailing spaces and newlines, etc.).

---

So as to have a (kind of) comprehensive answer, I'd like to add the following wonderful method. It's pointed out by [Thor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331399) in [this comment of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731328/number-of-folders-which-dont-have-subfolders#comment29317147_19731328), and refers to [Ben Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479989)'s [answer in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912513/how-to-use-bash-to-show-folders-that-have-two-subfolders/14917866#14917866) that I'll quote (with adaptations) below:

> [If your file system supports hardlinks] there is a much simpler solution that takes advantage of the fact that the parent directory links `..` from each subdirectory increase the link count of the directory by 1. A directory with no subdirectories has a link count of 2 (`.` and the link from its own parent by its name). Thus a directory with no subdirectories has a link count of 2 and can be found with this command:
>
> ```
> find . -type d -links 2
> ```
>
> It's not legal to make other hardlinks to a directory so there should be no false positives.